# Duckling timezone is ignored

Tags: duckling

I am passing to duckling a timezone, and it gets ignored by it, and sends the result with a timezone of the machine duckling is running.
In the docs, it says that it will be fixed shortly. any idea on when this fix will be coming?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please share your code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile till the issue gets fixed you can try to use reference time available in duckling and add/subtract time of your zone with respect to utc

Answer (score 0):

So What worked for me is to send the now of the user (reftime) and timezone UTC like so:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:8000/parse --data 'locale=en_GB&text=Today is now.&tz=UTC&reftime=1543801533000
```

reftime - The time form epoch UTC in millisecond.